# Given string and its substring, how could I add white space after substring using unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Assume the substring is unique, for example, given string,
`washington aveLansing, MI`
How could I locate the **street** and add a white space after it.
`washington ave Lansing, MI`

Comment: "street" and "ave" aren't the same string.

Comment: You need to give some more info. Is it a string pattern, a length, ... that define the separation between your *field* info

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your problem correctly. You are trying to add space after a pattern of string.

echo "washington aveLansing, MI" | sed -e "s/ave/ave /g"

Comment: The -e option is not needed. In here we don't need the global substituting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sed command. You can use the below example.

sed 's/ ave/ ave /'  <<<"washington aveLansing, MI"

It will work as you expected. If you want to give any other street name, you can modify the ave with the street name.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{sub("Lansing"," &");print}'  input
washington ave Lansing, MI
```

If you have more then one line use

```
awk '{sub("[A-Z]", " &", $2)}1' input
washington ave Lansing, MI
state street Chicago, IL
```